# How is Screen Time calculated? Why is the calculated time seemingly longer than time spent on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

Under [Screen Time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982), the report for the time spent on my phone is *1 hour 5 minutes*.
However, when looking at all the apps used, the time spent on the phone adds up to about *28 minutes* and not *1 hour 5 minutes*.

Time spent on iPhone for the full day:

[image]

But looking at all apps, the time spent is about *28 minutes*

[image]

---

- How is Screen Time calculated?
- Why is time spent on the iPhone calculated to  *1 hour 5 minutes* if time spent on all apps is really about *28 minutes*?

---

Note:

1. I'm using ios v14. iPhone SE 1st Generation.
2. The iPhone is supervised, (but I don't see why that would matter).
3. *Share Across Devices* is enabled, however, I don't own or use any other apple devices besides this iPhone (seemingly this shouldn't either matter).

Comment: Is sharing screen time over iCloud enabled and you own another Mac/iPhone/iPad ?

Comment: @X_841 sharing over iCloud is enabled. However, the only apple device that I have and use is my iPhone. I do not have have any other apple devices.

Comment: Note: The iPhone is _supervised_, but I don't see why that would matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug on ios 14.

From an [article on Medium.com](https://medium.com/macoclock/many-iphone-users-are-reporting-weird-screentime-issues-with-ios-14-2-aa98bff0ae9e):

> ...Turns out I’m not the only one seeing weird issues with screentime.
> There doesn’t seem to be a correlation in regards to the iPhone model.
> It also doesn’t seem to be a very common problem. However, others have
> been reporting other odd screentime glitches. Some have reported their
> screentime being inaccurately high with no app to blame. And others
> are also reporting that their phone claims they’ve spent hours on
> websites they’ve never visited.

---

My *Screen Time* claims that I was using my iPhone for 24Hours! *(let's hope I wasn't...).*

[image: ScreenTime bug]

I have visited [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) for about 1 minute, however, it's calculated as 24 hours.

[image]

Also, all apps were fully closed, no apps were running in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Since there is no screentime API available to developers I doubt anyone can tell how the calculation works. I think you might have the option to share across devices turned on. This includes screen time from all Apple devices that are using your apple email.

Comment: OP has already addressed in a comment, that they don't have any other Apple device other than their iPhone