# Screen Time shows 24hr usage for several weeks

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

Screen Time on my iPhone 8 (iOS 14.2) is reporting that the Wikipedia app has been running 24hrs a day for a few weeks. I don’t even have the Wikipedia app installed on my phone.

What’s going on and how can I fix it? I’m trying to use Screen Time to limit my usage, but now the statistics are completely messed up.

Comment: I just upgraded to iOS 14.3 -- which involves a power cycle -- and Screen Time is still reporting Wikipedia to be running constantly, despite it not being installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is Screen Time calculated? Why is the calculated time seemingly longer than time spent on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409973/how-is-screen-time-calculated-why-is-the-calculated-time-seemingly-longer-than)